# Can not download a streamable m3u8 link with IDM and ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, download, m3u8

This is the link:    https://v13.phephim.xyz/vod/v2/packaged:mp4/6005b3591918ee01c9ef67e4/playlist.m3u8

It's ok to play the link with *play-hls-m3u8* chrome extension or by the site *https://www.hlsplayer.net/* but I got errors when trying to download it by ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i https://v13.phephim.xyz/vod/v2/packaged:mp4/6005b3591918ee01c9ef67e4/playlist.m3u8 -c copy OUTPUT.MP4
```

Full log:

```
   ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[hls @ 0x561c95a74c40] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0x561c95a74c40] Opening 'https://v13.phephim.xyz/vod/v2/packaged:mp4/6005b3591918ee01c9ef67e4/0.ts?e=ad32a6dc7559f830a29b88ca30b975d90daef6578a563b09e97c798063c39de9fc124d470f75ad0220b9f440b7bd6767' for reading
[hls @ 0x561c95a74c40] Opening 'https://v13.phephim.xyz/vod/v2/packaged:mp4/6005b3591918ee01c9ef67e4/1.ts?e=e9b0a737f46906cdb4d67aed95e65ae4ab8eb401100eebce4e711ffdaf43c68fc2d8a49add4295587b38fe90c9d4cf86' for reading
[hls @ 0x561c95a74c40] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: png, none(pc)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, hls, from 'https://v13.phephim.xyz/vod/v2/packaged:mp4/6005b3591918ee01c9ef67e4/playlist.m3u8':
  Duration: 01:02:06.42, bitrate: 0 kb/s
  Program 0 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, none(pc), 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
Output #0, mp4, to 'OUTPUT.MP4':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

I have tried to add some other command options but still got the same errors.

Doing devtools inspect, I found
the .ts segment link redirected to another link that has the response header:

```
content-disposition: inline;filename="unnamed.png"
content-type: image/png
```

Is it normal?

Image: [response header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI7Gi.jpg)

Pls help me to download the video. Thanks!

p/s: sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 4):

The service is purposely corrupting the stream, most likely as a form of cheap DRM. This is done very much on purpose, and no existing software or or program will be able to play this stream.

Each video file is prepended with a 1px x 1px white PNG image. A player specifically modified to discard the PNG at the start of each segment can easy play this back.

Comment: Ohh that sounds new to me.
Can I do the job with ffmpeg, or is there any available player? Any suggestion?
And I wonder how online players could play this vid like the normals?

Comment: Please re read my answer. I answered all those questions. I specifically said "no existing software or or program will be able to play this stream". And "I wonder how online players could play this vid like the normals" They are "specifically modified to discard the PNG". I'm not sure why you asked three follow up question THAT WERE ALREADY ANSWERED!

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood it.
Thank you so much for the answers!